# Need command-line program to download all of http:// https:// scp:// ftp:// style links (on e.g. ubuntu)

Tags: command-line, scp, perl, ftp, http

I'm writing a perl program where I want to accept all kinds of "file names" from the user, including `/home/foo/bar.txt` and `scp://server/some/file.txt` or whatever. And then I thought that if I can find a cmd line program that does it, I'll find a perl module that does it too, or I'll just run it through perl's `system()` call.

I thought of cURL and/or lftp, but on ubuntu, I get:

```
> curl scp://server/some/file
curl: (1) Protocol scp not supported or disabled in libcurl
> lftp -c 'get scp://server/some/file'
get: scp - not supported protocol
```

For curl I investigated why that was on Ubuntu and found [curl and pycurl is not compiled with sftp support](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/curl/+bug/311029) - basically it *ain't gonna happen* unless I recompile libcurl*, but I don't want to require my users to apply a patch to libcurl*.

Sure, I can write it myself as in:

```
if ($proto eq 'scp') {
    # handle scp
    open I, 'scp ...' or die;
} elsif ($proto eq 'http') {
    open I, 'wget ...' or die;
} else {
    # whatever
}
```

But I'd much rather somebody else write/test/debug that with a huge list of protocols and I'm surprised I couldn't find anything that does this out-of-the-box! Do you know of any that I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe protocol name is sftp, not scp.

In my system, following works: `lftp -c 'get sftp://someserver/file'`, as well as ftp and http.

Comment: Yup, you're right. I investigated curl didn't support either of scp or sftp and didn't bother checking that for lftp too. Sorry for the noise! I'll use lftp!

Comment: SCP and SFTP are distinct protocols. An SSH server can be configured to accept one but not the other, though I doubt there are many that accept SFTP but not SCP. And then there are FTPS, FISH and a few others.

Comment: yep, you are right